# How to allow only a valid floating point number into a text field in android

Tags: android

How to allow only a valid floating point number into a text field floating point like these only

2.353
-2.354
4444.45

Comment: Your all example values are valid floating point numbers, which one you want check for invalid?

Comment: I believe you are asking to validate some specific floating values, rite?

Answer (score 2):

Implement a focus listener on the field. When the focus changes from the textfield to any other part of your form simply use a regexp to check the validity of the input.

Something like :

```
^(-)?\d*(\.\d*)?$
```

Should do the trick.

Then use the pattern matching of Android to see if the input matches the regexp :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-)?\d*(\.\d*)?$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if (m.find()) { 
    ////Found
}
else {
  //Not found
}
```

But be aware of local settings...In France for example, the dot(.) used to separate the decimals is in fact a comma(,)

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) to achieve this.

```
//value pool
final String[] check = new String[]{"2.353","-2.354","4444.45"};

 yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            String s = ((EditText)v).getText().toString().trim();

            for(String tmp : check){
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(s) && s.equals(tmp)){
                    //it ok
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

For edittext use `android:inputType="number"`

Convert the resulting string into an integer (e.g., Integer.parseInt(myEditText.getText().toString())`).

Answer (score -1):

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```